# pfsense multi-site VPN VOIP deployment

Tags: vpn, voip, pfsense

have main office pfsense firewall configured like this:

local networks
WAN  -> internet
LAN  -> local network
VOIP -> IP phones

need to connect remote offices (multi-users) and single remote users (from home)
use IPSEC or OpenVPN to build "permanent" automatically connecting
tunnels from remote location to main location.

in remote locations, network will look like this:
WAN -> internet
LAN  -> local network multiple users
VOIP -> multiple IP phones

in order for the IP phones to work they have to be able to "see" the VOIP network and the
VOIP server back at the main office

for single remote users ( like from home ) the setup will be similar but only one phone
and one computer

so questions:

best way to tie networks together?  IPSEC or OpenVPN
can this be setup to automatically connect ?

any issues/suggestions with that design/topology ?

QoS or issues with running the VOIP traffic over a VPN 
throughput, quality etc.. obviously depends on remote locations connection to some degree

Answer (score 1):

Either IPsec or OpenVPN will meet your needs there. In general, either are equally suited from your description. There's a lot more to it than that, more than I can detail here, which is detailed in the pfSense book. http://pfsense.org/book